# Integrating the Facebook like function with a web banner

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-like, banner

I want to have a web banner that when you click on it, it automatically likes my Facebook page. Is this possible? If so can someone point me in the right direction of similar to coding.

I want the functionality of a like button with my own image.

Answer (score 3):

this is NOT a good thing to do - a like button should be the classic like button of facebook.
If it could look like anything then people could be tricked into liking something.
Do NOT attempt to do this.
You will make people very mad... you don't want to be deceiving your users...
You can [read here  for more information about the Facebook Platform Policies](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/)

Taken from the link above :

> You must not obscure or cover elements of our social plugins, such as
>   the Like button or Like box plugin.

You are referring to obscuring the like button... ie - making it not look like the original like button